# Is there any method to find the index of tree leaf node for PrimeNG tree

Tags: angular, treeview, primeng, primeng-tree

I need to make buttons for going next and previous from the selected leaf nodes, and was thinking of using the index.
Is there a way to get the index, I looked in the documents, it does show a parent property for defining in a node, but no relevant example I could use.
leaf node currently have:

```
icon: "pi pi-globe"
label: "g-d-i-0.jpg"
leaf: true
parent: undefined
```